# Sum of matrix inverses

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

I am trying to compute the following finite sum:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\left(A+\lambda_iB\right)^{-1}$$

In this sum, $A$ and $B$ are are positive-definite matrices (so they are inversible). The $\lambda_i$ are positive numbers so the sums $\left(A+\lambda_iB\right)$ are also positive-definite (and inversible).

Is there a way to factor or rewrite this sum in a way where we can only compute $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ once instead of having to inverse so many matrices?

I tried to use Woodbury's identity but I couldn't simplify the sum much. I could also rewrite the sum as:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n B^{-1}\left(B^{-1}+\lambda_iA^{-1}\right)^{-1}A^{-1}$$
but it doesn't really simplify the problem.

**Edit:**
To simplify the problem we can instead compute the following sum:
$$S(\lambda) = \sum_{i=1}^n\left(I+\lambda_iC\right)^{-1}$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix and $C$ is another positive-definite matrix.

Comment: I assume it is a finite sum?

Comment: Yes, it is a finite sum, I'll edit the post to make it clear.

Comment: If you know the SVD of $C$, you can easily derive the SVD of $S$.

Comment: @Damien can you explain how? Computing the SVD is quite simple in my case and that could help.

Comment: @PC1. Sorry, I could not answer, night here. But you made it yourself! Better.

Comment: @Damien indeed - you provided a good hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually as $C$ is semi-definite positive, we can diagonalize it and write $C = PDP^\dagger$, where $D$ is diagonal and $P^{-1}=P^\dagger$. So, using some simple matrix algebra:

\begin{align*}
(I+\lambda C)^{-1}&=(I+\lambda PDP^\dagger)^{-1} \\
&=\left[(PP^\dagger)(I+\lambda PDP^\dagger)(PP^\dagger)\right]^{-1} \\
&=\left[P(I+\lambda D)P^\dagger\right]^{-1} \\
&=P(I+\lambda D)^{-1}P^\dagger \\
\end{align*}

In this case, the inversion is trivial as $I$ and $D$ are both diagonal matrices and we can easily write the sum without inverting any matrix.